# Rebuild oracle hierarchical query from two tables

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, hierarchical-query

I am working on oracle hierarchical query for the below table 
`Classification_Product` and `Order_details` tables

Classification Product has the `Classification_id` which will be stored in the `Order_details`according to user selection

Classification Product table
[image: Classification Product table]

Order_details table
[image: Order_details table]

I want to select all products from `Order_details` table that has a parent `LED Screen` which will return all product that has parent `LED Screen` no matter what the child is 32inch or 50 inch or sony samsung etc etc

I tried to use below query but its replate rows a lot

```
           SELECT B.CLASSIFICATION_ID, LEVEL AS VLEVEL, A.CATEGORY_ID, A.CATEGORY_DESC, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS leaf
             FROM PRODUCT_CLASSIFICATION A, ORDER_DETAILS B
            WHERE A.STATUS = 1 and b.created_on like sysdate--AND leaf =1 
       START WITH A.CATEGORY_ID IS NULL
       CONNECT BY A.CATEGORY_ID = PRIOR A.CLASSIFICATION_ID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY A.CLASSIFICATION_ID;
```

Comment: First the query duplicate the records because you don't add a where condition to relation the B table with A, then for each record on B table duplicate the result on A table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select od.*
from order_details od
where
  od.classification_id in (
    select p.classification_id
    from product p
    start with p.category_desc = 'LED Screen'
    connect by prior p.classification_id = p.category_id
  )
```